# Can I use FirebaseMessagingService to request single location update and make network request?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-workmanager

I have a FirebaseMessagingService:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        requestLocationUpdates()
    }
}
```

What I want is to request location updates when message is received:

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                for (location in locationResult.locations) {
                 
                }
            }
        }
```

Is it legal? Or I should start separate service or even create a Work by WorkManager?

Comment: I've worked on a similar application. A service is preferred if you need continuous background location update. but you need to take care of the android OS because android OS will kill the application if it is not in use like in my case it was 15 to 30 minutes depending upon the OS. A workaround for this is to create an un-killable service or use of wakelock manager in your application. Also you need to take of the battery consumption for this as location drains too much battery. Also if you need it after some longer interval workmanager can also work well and for my case i used the service.